# Calculate consumer and producer surplus (area between curves)

Tags: integration, finance

Supply Function: $X_S(p)=ln(\frac{e^2}{4}p)$

Demand Function: $X_D(p)=\sqrt{20-4p}$

Equilibrium price $EP=4$ , Equilibrium quantity $EQ= 2$

$y=2$

How do you calculate the consumer/producer surplus, when the supply and demand function start at different $p$ values?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In accordance with your second image (and if I understand correctly), the consumer surplus equals the integral of the demand curve from $0$ to $EQ$ minus $EQ\cdot EP$. Similary, the producer surplus equals $EQ\cdot EP$ minus the integral from $0$ to $EQ$ of the supply curve.
*Remark.* You switched up the equilibirum quantity and price, since we have $X_D(4)=X_S(4)=\underbrace2_{\text{equilibrium price}}$. So we have $EQ=4$ and $EP=2$.

So the consumer surplus equals
$$\int_0^{\overbrace4^{\text{EQ}}} \sqrt{20 - 4 p} \,\mathrm d p - 2\cdot 4 = \left[ -\frac14(20 - 4 p)^\frac32 \cdot \frac23 \right]^{p=4}_{p=0}-8 = \frac43(5\sqrt 5 -1)-8\approx5.57.$$

Similarly, the producer surplus equals
$$8 - \int_0^4 \ln\left(\frac{\exp(2)}4 p\right)\,\mathrm dp=8-\left[p + p\log(p/4)\right]^4_0=8-4=4.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i just figured it out. You have to keep in mind that the second image has the quantitiy on the x-axis, and price on the y-axis ($p(x)$). But we have it the other way around ($x(p)$). So basically you need to mirror the second image along $y=x$ to get to our first image situation. The interval for the surplus function cant start at $0$, because $0$ is not in our economic domain of definition (quantity cant be $< 0$). So the interval for the surplus function starts at $\frac{4}{e^2}$ and ends at 4, and the interval for the demand function starts at 4 and ends at 5